# Transactional messaging API not sending to cc'ed recipient

Tags: marketing-cloud, transactional-messaging-api

I've a send definition setup via API which looks like this

```
{
    "name": "unique send definition name",
    "definitionKey": "unique send definition key",
    "description": "Created via REST",
    "classification": "Transactional_test_classification",
    "status": "Active",
    "createdDate": "2021-01-22T01:35:00",
    "modifiedDate": "2021-01-22T01:35:00",
    "content": {
        "customerKey": "-omitted-"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "dataExtension": "myDataExt",
        "list": "myList",
        "autoAddSubscriber": false,
        "updateSubscriber": true
    },
    "options": {
        "trackLinks": true,
        "cc": [
            "jonappleseed@example.com"
        ]
    },
    "journey": {
        "interactionKey": "-omitted-"
    }
}
```

When triggering this by API call to POST /messaging/v1/email/messages/{messageKey}, everything appears normal. The email is properly delivered to the main recipient but jonappleseed@example.com never gets the cc email.

Is there any hidden options to enable cc/bcc on this use case?

Comment: did you try changing the cc value to some other test address to rule out some deliverability issue?

Comment: @PeterNoges yes, first thing I did was try other email addresses and domains gmail/yahoo etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to use CC/BCC in other portions of the application? Typically this feature is not turned on unless requested via a support ticket.

While the configuration for the message definition can be set via the API, if the feature is not enabled it will have no effect.

You can do a quick check by looking at an email activity in Journey Builder to see the CC/BCC options in the Advanced Options of an email message.

[image]

Comment: The journey was created via API and there seems to be no way to get to the email activity option after the journey was created.

Comment: Daniel, you'll need to patch the definition (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateMessageDefinition.htm) with an empty value in the cc array: 

"options": {
        "cc": []
    }